# Being forced to git pull and merge an empty commit

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature branch, `logs`, that was branched off of `master`.

The branch has been pushed to remote github.

It sat there for a while, I recently was going to make some changes so I rebased off master, which went fine, made my new commits, but then when I try to push I get:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

and -

```
 Your branch and 'origin/logs' have diverged,
    and have 621 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
      (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Is git being upset something to do with the fact that I rebased? If I do a git pull and merge, it's an empty commit, how do I avoid this?

Comment: It sounds like commits to `origin/logs` were made that you didn't have on your local repository.  Is that possible?  If so, rebase wouldn't be the way to go with this.

Comment: I don't believe that to be the case, I'm the only one who worked off of `origin/logs` and it was just one commit. Master had new updates I needed to use with `origin/logs`, so I rebased. I suppose I don't really need to rebase, since I know my update work, so I could just merge it with master, but I'm curious why I cant rebase, in a different situation I may have needed to rebase to finish the work.

Comment: In my mind, what happened was that the rebase against master *introduced* those 621 commits.  You're divergent right now because you had work on your remote that was against an earlier ancestor of master.  Can you at least confirm if the change (the code, not necessarily the SHA) from your remote is contained in your local branch?